# Creating a flexible email message

Tags: javascript, html, email, attr

I am trying to create an email message that confirms the date before it creates the message. The code below is what I have come up with, but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
function Report(emailName, addresseList){
    document.writeln('<a id="comparisonReport" onClick="promptDate(this,\'' + addresseList + '\')" href="">' + emailName + '</a><br />');
}

function promptDate(obj, addresseList){
    d = new Date(prompt("What is the report date?",""));
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(d) !== "[object Date]") {
        obj.attr('href', 'mailto:' + addresseList + '?subject=' + "Report " + d + '&body=' + "Here is the report for " + d + ".");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, here you’re creating a date:

```
d = new Date(prompt("What is the report date?",""));
```

And here you’re checking that it’s not a date before continuing:

```
if (Object.prototype.toString.call(d) !== "[object Date]") {
```

It’s always going to be a date. Try checking `if (!isNaN(d))` instead, if you were checking for a *valid* date. Also, turn on strict mode and declare `d`.

Comment: What do you mean by turn on strict mode?

Comment: @Makai: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode